# C code permutation

Tags: c, permutation

Here is a permutation code, however it does not print all possible permutations. only printed is the input. What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bitmask;
char* characters;
int characters_count;
char* running;
int running_count;
void permutations() {
    int i;
    if (running_count == characters_count) {
        printf("%s\n", running);
    } else {
        for (i=0; i<characters_count; i++) {
            if ( ((bitmask>>i)&1) == 0 ) {
                running[running_count] = characters[i];
                bitmask |= (1<<i);
                running_count = running_count + 1;
                permutations();
                running_count = running_count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

main() {
    int i;
    int cases;

    characters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    scanf("%s", characters);
    characters_count = strlen(characters);

    running = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    memset(running, 0, 30);
    running_count = 0;

    permutations();

    free(characters);
    free(running);
}
```

sample input

```
ab
```

sample output

```
ab
```

instead of

```
ab
ba
```

My friend thinks only one line is some mistake here. But I can't figure it out what line is the wrong one or line that I am lacking

Comment: you need restore `bitmask` after  `permutations();`.

Comment: Or just make it local to `permutations`.

Comment: @Mauris: making it local to `permutations` does not work, but you can make it an argument to `permutations` and pass the modified value `bitmask | (1<<i)` when recursing.

Comment: @chqrlie how can i do that without making it an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your code this way:

```
    bitmask |= (1<<i);
    running_count = running_count + 1;
    permutations();
    running_count = running_count - 1;
    bitmask &= ~(1<<i);
```

But it would be much better to not rely on global variables.

Memory allocation in `main` is also unnecessary, given the fixed buffer size.

Here is a version without memory allocation, not global variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void permutations(int bitmask,
                  const char *characters, int characters_count,
                  char *running, int running_count) {
    if (running_count == characters_count) {
        printf("%.*s\n", running_count, running);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters_count; i++) {
            if (((bitmask >> i) & 1) == 0) {
                running[running_count] = characters[i];
                permutations(bitmask | (1 << i),
                             characters, characters_count,
                             running, running_count + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char characters[30];
    char running[30];

    if (scanf("%29s", characters) == 1) {
        permutations(0, characters, strlen(characters), running, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also notice the `%.*s` `printf` conversion specifier to print only the first `running_count` chars from `running`, and the `%29s` `scanf` specifier to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: Nice explanation. I see that yours is way better. Thank you :)